# R's table function in Julia (for DataFrames)

Tags: dataframe, julia

Is there something like R's table function in Julia? I've read about `xtab`, but do not know how to use it.

Suppose we have R's `data.frame` `rdata` which `col6` is of the `Factor` type.

R sample code:

`rdata <- read.csv("mycsv.csv") #1
table(rdata$col6) #2`

In order to read data and make factors in Julia I do it like this:

`using DataFrames
jldata = readtable("mycsv.csv", makefactors=true) #1 :col6 will be now pooled.`

..., but how to build R's table like in julia (how to achieve #2)?

Comment: See this ongoing discussion at: [StatsBase](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/issues/32)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that a similar effect can be achieved using `by`:

Let `jldata` consists of `:gender` column.

`julia> by(jldata, :gender, nrow)
3x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | gender   | x1    |
|-----|----------|-------|
| 1   | NA       | 175   |
| 2   | "female" | 40254 |
| 3   | "male"   | 58574 |`

Of course it's not a `table` but at least I get the same data type as the datasource. Surprisingly `by` seems to be faster than `countmap`.

Comment: that's really neat. I prefer this over `countmap` for dataframes.

Comment: It might be worth adding that this method can be used to do multiple cross-tabulations, which `countmap` can't do at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `countmap` function from `StatsBase.jl` to count the entries of a single variable. General cross tabulation and statistical tests for contingency tables are lacking at this point. As Ismael points out, this has been discussed in the issue tracker for `StatsBase.jl`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe, "by" is depreciated in Julia as of 1.5.3 (It says: ERROR: ArgumentError: by function was removed from DataFrames.jl).

So here are some alternatives, we can use split apply combine to do a cross tabs as well or use FreqTables.

**Using Split Combine:**

**Example 1 - SingleColumn**:

```
using RDatasets
using DataFrames

mtcars = dataset("datasets", "mtcars")

## To do a table on cyl column

gdf = groupby(mtcars, :Cyl)
combine(gdf, nrow)
```

**Output:**

```
#    3×2 DataFrame
#     Row │ Cyl    nrow
#         │ Int64  Int64
#    ─────┼──────────────
#       1 │     6      7
#       2 │     4     11
#       3 │     8     14
```

**Example 2 - CrossTabs Between 2 columns**:

```
## we have to just change the groupby code a little bit and rest is same

gdf = groupby(mtcars, [:Cyl, :AM])
combine(gdf, nrow)
```

**Output**:

```
#6×3 DataFrame
# Row │ Cyl    AM     nrow
#     │ Int64  Int64  Int64
#─────┼─────────────────────
#   1 │     6      1      3
#   2 │     4      1      8
#   3 │     6      0      4
#   4 │     8      0     12
#   5 │     4      0      3
#   6 │     8      1      2
```

Also on a side note if you don't like the name as nrow on top, you can use :
`combine(gdf, nrow => :Count)`
to change the name to Count

**Alternate way: Using FreqTables**

You can use package, `FreqTables` like below to do count and proportion very easily, to add it you can use `Pkg.add("FreqTables")` :

```
## Cross tab between cyl and am
freqtable(mtcars.Cyl, mtcars.AM)

## Proportion between cyl and am
prop(freqtable(mtcars.Cyl, mtcars.AM))

## with margin like R you can use it too in this (columnwise proportion: margin=2)
 prop(freqtable(mtcars.Cyl, mtcars.AM), margins=2)

## with margin for rowwise proportion: margin = 1
 prop(freqtable(mtcars.Cyl, mtcars.AM), margins=1)
```

**Outputs:**

```
## count cross tabs
#3×2 Named Array{Int64,2}
#Dim1 ╲ Dim2 │  0   1
#────────────┼───────
#4           │  3   8
#6           │  4   3
#8           │ 12   2

## proportion wise (overall)
#3×2 Named Array{Float64,2}
#Dim1 ╲ Dim2 │       0        1
#────────────┼─────────────────
#4           │ 0.09375     0.25
#6           │   0.125  0.09375
#8           │   0.375   0.0625


## Column wise proportion
#3×2 Named Array{Float64,2}
#Dim1 ╲ Dim2 │        0         1
#────────────┼───────────────────
#4           │ 0.157895  0.615385
#6           │ 0.210526  0.230769
#8           │ 0.631579  0.153846

## Row wise proportion
#3×2 Named Array{Float64,2}
#Dim1 ╲ Dim2 │        0         1
#────────────┼───────────────────
#4           │ 0.272727  0.727273
#6           │ 0.571429  0.428571
#8           │ 0.857143  0.142857
```